# UE4 Object doesn't rotate around its pivot in Sequencer

Tags: rotation, pivot, unreal-engine4

I'm having a problem with rotation of object in a short animation inside UE4's Sequencer.

It needs to rotate and pivot around the center of its base: when I set the pivot of the object to the center of its base and rotate it with vieport's object rotation tool all goes well as expected in the viewport itself.

But once I am in the animation in Sequencer and try to rotate my object there with the object's transformation Yaw control (equivalent of Z axis - that is the vertical one, right?) viewing Sequencer output in the viewport (clicking the small camera besides the camera object line in the Sequencer) my object's position is flying all over the place as it does not rotate around its pivot center although I set it in the center of its base - it looks like it is orbiting around some fictional center point way off from my object, so my object is making strange circles instead of rotating around its base on vertical Y (Z in UE4) axis.

​​​​​​​Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it, that is how to make Sequencer rotation values behave exactly as the rotation tool in Viewport?